# couchbase metadata overhead warning. 62% RAM is taken up by keys and metadata

Tags: couchbase, nosql

<del>Okay since i don't have 10 repitation I'm unable to post images, but I will try to explain in text.</del>

I have a 7 node Couchbase (Community) cluster with 4 buckets.
Recently I've been getting spammed(constantly) by Metadata overhead warnings for one of the buckets..
The warning pops up and looks like this:

Metadata overhead warning. Over 62% of RAM allocated to bucket XXXX on node "xxx" is taken up by keys and metadata.

And I've read that it is usually a sign that the bucket needs more ram. But I don't thing that is the issue for me. I simply have a lot of metadata I would guess.
When I look at the **Data Buckets** tab this bucket has **RAM/Quota Usage** *64GB/75GB*. So for me it looks that there is around 11GB(75-64GB) available.
[image: bucket overview]

If i look at the Bucket Analytics **VBUCKET RESOURCES** metrics I see that there is *59GB* **user data** in RAM and *46GB* **metadata** in RAM. So to my understanding there should be 105GB in RAM on a bucket that has a total of 75GB!?!

But that doesn't add up for me so clearly there is something that I don't understand here.
And yes 46GB of 75GB is around 62%. But what about the 59GB user data that is supposedly in RAM?
[image: Bucket Analytics]

*EDIT*:
A typical document can look like this:

```
ID=1:CAESEA---rldZ5PhdV4msSdEchI
CONTENT=z2TjZEzkZ84=
```

And to my question. What do I do? Is the situation acceptable in my circumstances. If so, do I change the threshold for that warning(which I read is not recommended since the warning is set at 50% for a reason).

Or do I assign more RAM? And if so how does that help me if there is already 11GB free?

Please help me clarify these numbers and suggest if I need to take any actions.

Comment: Do I add the screenshots now that I have +10 rep?

Comment: What is your average value size for that ~200 million objects? How much RAM per node are you running?

Not that it is exactly related, but it looks like you are using swap space. What OS are you using and if Linux, is your swappiness set to 0. Also, I see that your resident object in RAM is only 5.27%. Is that on purpose as you are ejecting quite a bit of stuff there.

Comment: Key is about 29 bytes. Value is about 8 bytes.
Linux, 256GB RAM/node, swappiness=0
The screenshots where taken during a high surge of new items. Went from 50m to around 200m. Now that it's stabilized cache miss is 0.115 and active docs is 43%(which still is low)
couchbase use around 66% RAM. Rest is used by cache.
The reason for swap beeing used is that swappiness was set to 1 a while back. And I guess that is just remnants of swap that haven't been accessed since.. But I have now also allocated more RAM to this bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there isn't necessarily a problem with having a high percentage of memory used by metadata - it just means there's less RAM available for caching actual documents. If your application is working well then it may be fine for your use-case. However, having said that let me try and address your questions on it, and what to change if you do want to improve things:

> If i look at the Bucket Analytics VBUCKET RESOURCES metrics I see that there is 59GB user data in RAM and 46GB metadata in RAM. So to my understanding there should be 105GB in RAM on a bucket that has a total of 75GB!?!

IIRC "user data in RAM" is *inclusive* of "metadata in RAM" - so you have a total of 59 GB data used, of which 46 GB is metadata.

> And to my question. What do I do? Is the situation acceptable in my circumstances. If so, do I change the threshold for that warning(which I read is not recommended since the warning is set at 50% for a reason).
>   Or do I assign more RAM? And if so how does that help me if there is already 11GB free?

So basically you are storing lots of very small documents, so the per-document metadata overhead (~48 bytes plus the length of the key) is very high compared to the actual document size.

The 11GB free is mainly made up of the difference between the bucket quota and the high watermark.

Here are a few options to improve this:

1. **Allocate more RAM to the bucket** (as you mentioned) - if there's any unallocated in the Server Quota.
2. **Add more memory to the nodes** (and allocate to the server quota and bucket).
3. **Reduce the number of replicas** (if that's acceptable to you) - at the moment you are essentially storing each object (and it's metadata) three times - once for the active vBuckets and twice for the two replica vBucket sets.
4. **Change your documents to have shorter keys** - This will reduce the average metadata per document.
5. **Consolidate multiple documents into one** - This will reduce the number of documents, and hence the overall metadata overhead.

Comment: I've done 1. since I do have spare RAM. But for a more longterm solution I think I will try to do 4. and 5.